Error after upgrading from angular 15 to 16 : "Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected value 'TranslateModule' imported by the module 'AgilityModule'"
We are trying to upgrade from angular 14 to 17.
Ran the commands:
ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 @angular-eslint/schematics@15
and
ng update @angular/material@15 @angular/cdk@15.
The application ran without any error.
Then we ran update commands for version 16, after upgrading to 16 and running a build for the code, the following error is shown:
Error: node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/public_api.d.ts:22:53 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

22     static forRoot(config?: TranslateModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders;

We updated the tsconfig.app.json file by adding skiplibcheck = true to fix this as mentioned in the post.
Now ng build is successful but unable to browse the application. Below is the error that is thrown in the console:
zone.js:1043 Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected value 'TranslateModule' imported by the module 'AgilityModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Unexpected value 'TranslateModule' imported by the module 'AgilityModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

Any idea why this is failing?

did you upgrade ngx-translate as well?

Yes updated ngx translate, See the below lines from package.json file
"@ngx-translate/core": "15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "8.0.0",
